# how i can convert xml containing hebrew text to json

Tags: android

how can convert this XML code to JSON. Hebrew text will not be changed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<emp>
<id>01</id>
<name>חורחה</name>
</emp>
```

Comment: By parsing XML and generating JSON?
What is your problem?

Comment: yes, after converting in json, hebrew text is changed

Comment: Please provide sample of code showing how do you trying to convert.
Most probable cause is a wrong character encoding specified.

Comment: jsonObject = XML.toJSONObject(xml);

Comment: It will be better if you follow guideline about examples and place it in the question body: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you call `org.json.XML.toJSONObject(String)` you should check:

1. Ensure that actual XML encoding is UTF-8, as stated in `<?xml ...`
2. Ensure that you read it from file in correct encoding.
3. Ensure that you write resulting JSON to the file in the correct way and correct encoding.